# batch program keeps giving me "missing operand" errors

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, operands

when i run the code which is suppose to divide two numbers and give a output, or terminate when using the number 66; it tells me i have missing operands?

```
@Echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%x in (1, 0, 10) DO (
Set /p "num1=Enter num1: "
if "%num1%" == "66" (
GOTO EOF
)

Set /P "num2=Enter num2: "

set /a "sum4=%num1% / %num2%"
echo result: !sum4!

if "%num2%" == "0" (
  echo Number not valid, 0 entered
) 
IF NOT "%num2%" == "0" (
  set /a "sum5=%num1% / %num2%"
  echo result: !sum5!
)
)
pause
:EOF
cls
echo Program has ended
```

Comment: you need delayed expansion

Comment: Is this the line that is missing operands: `set /a "sum4=%num1% / %num2%"` ?You should check for %num2% equals zero before you ever try to divide by it.

Comment: What inputs are you giving it? How far into the script are you getting? Show us the output. Take the [tour], read [ask].

Comment: @jwdonahue after inputting the two variables i get my output look like this: 'missing operand. result:' after which it keeps repeating until terminated by typing 66 for the first variable

Comment: @M.Street, [edit] your post.

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `set /?`. The help file is long but does talk about how to use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

try like this (I'm using the same logic as you):

```
@Echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%x in (1, 0, 10) DO (
    Set /p "num1=Enter num1: "
    if "!num1!" == "66" (
        call :END
    )

    Set /P "num2=Enter num2: "

    set /a "sum4=!num1! / !num2!"
    echo result: !sum4!

    if "!num2!" == "0" (
      echo Number not valid, 0 entered
    ) 
    IF NOT "!num2!" == "0" (
      set /a "sum5=!num1! / !num2!"
      echo result: !sum5!
    )
)
pause
exit /b
:END
cmd /k & exit
```

it is not so easy to exit an infinite `FOR /L` loop so here I've used exit command and I'm starting a new cmd process in the same console. May be there's a better way.

The reason for the missing operand error was because you weren't using the `!` for variable exapnsion everywhere when needed (despite you've activated the delayed expansion)

Comment: Typo: `if "1num2!" == "0" (`

Comment: @npocmaka oh, ok i thought the ! operand was only for the result of the expression. thank you

Comment: No need to expand the variables with `SET /A`. `set /a "sum4=num1/num2"` works just as well. But the delayed expansion is needed with other statements like `IF` and `ECHO`.